# Is it possible to hide Empty Bar In primeng Bar charts?

Tags: angular, primeng

Is it possible to hide bar if there is no value present in it? Currently it is giving empty space if there is null or empty value and I don't need that.
I didn't find anything useful in the documentation or stack overflow
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chart/bar

```
export class BarChartDemo {

    basicData: any;
    
    basicOptions: any;

    multiAxisData: any;

    chartOptions: any;

    multiAxisOptions: any;

    stackedData: any;

    stackedOptions: any;
    
    subscription: Subscription;

    config: AppConfig;

    constructor(private configService: AppConfigService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.basicData = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: '#42A5F5',
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                },
                {
                    label: 'My Second dataset',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFA726',
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                }
            ]
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting `skipNull` to true as instructed in Chart.js documentation;
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#general